# help in inserting a word in a string at position specified

Tags: c++

I made a code that would insert a word entered by the user in a string at specified position.for example if string is :alice wonderland,word is in and pos is 6,op/ should be:   alicein wonderland 
But,the code isn't working.Can u tell me the flaws?
here's the code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char str[100],word[50];
    int i,len,p,f,w;
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter string"<<endl;
    gets(str);
    cout<<"Enter word and position"<<endl;
    gets(word);
    cin>>p;
    for(len=0;str[len!='\0';len++);
    for(w=0;word[w]!='\0';w++);
    for(i=len-1;i>=p-1;i--)
       str[i+w]=str[i];
    for(i=p-1;f=0;f<w;f++,i++)
       str[i]=word[f];
    str[len+w-1]='\0';
    cout<<"Modified string..."<<endl;
    puts(str);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: You should start using C++ style. This means including your headers without the extension. Eg. `#include <iostream>` and `#include <cstdio>`. You should be using `cin`, `cout`, `getline()`, etc for your IO, instead of `stdio.h` stuff like `gets()`. You should declare variables just before you use them, instead of at the beginning of the function. Also, some whitespace (blank lines) and comments would be nice, to give the reader's brain a break.

Comment: I'd fix your compile errors first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code, as provided, will not compile. Are you having issues compiling the code? I'll ignore the syntax errors and point out the logic errors. Change the third for loop into

```
for(i=len-1;i>=p;i--) // note 'p-1' was changed to 'p'
   str[i+w]=str[i];
```

Change the fourth for loop to

```
for(i=p;f=0;f<w;f++,i++) // again, note the 'p-1' changed to 'p'
   str[i]=word[f];
```

Lastly, change the `str[len+w-1]='\0';` to `str[len+w]='\0';`
The logic errors with your code are essentially an "off by one" error. In each case, removing the -1 should fix the errors.